# Responsive layout not displaying properly on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, layout

When I shrink the screen down, it appears like it does in the image. I put it in as Visual Composer's "Raw HTML" option, originally with a 4 item layout, which worked fine. I changed the percentages for a 6 column layout on a desktop view (3 on tablet), but this is just not displaying right.

Help, please?

[image]
CSS

```
.contentBox {
    padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
}
.allImg {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.arrow,
.collectionCopy {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.collectionCopy a p {
    text-align: left;
}
.arrow {
    min-height: 14px;
    min-width: 14px;
}

.collectionCopy p {
    display: block;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.collectionCopy p:first-child {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
            margin-top: -4px; 
}

.collectionCopy p:last-child {
    color: #676767;
    font-color: #e1e1e1;
            margin-top: -4px;
            margin-left: 0;
}

.collectionInfo {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.collectionInfo a,
.arrow a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.collectionImg {
    float: left;
    padding: 16px 8px;
    width: 16.66%;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

.collectionImg a img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 420px) and (max-width: 995px) {
    .collectionImg {
        width: 33%;
        padding: 8px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 420px) {
    .collectionImg {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 32px;
    }

    .allImg {
        padding: 0;
    }

}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="allImg">

        <div class="collectionImg">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/OT854_espresso_top.jpg"></a>

            <div class="collectionInfo">

                <div class="arrow">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/arrow.png"/></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collectionCopy">
                    <a href="#">
                    <p>Harbourne</p>
                    <p>Colourways (7)</p>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end collectionInfo -->

        </div> <!-- end collectionImg -->

        <div class="collectionImg">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/OT854_sable_top.jpg"></a>

            <div class="collectionInfo">

                <div class="arrow">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/arrow.png"/></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collectionCopy">
                    <a href="#">
                    <p>Harbourne</p>
                    <p>Colourways (7)</p>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end collectionInfo -->

        </div> <!-- end collectionImg -->

        <div class="collectionImg">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/OT850_toffee_top.jpg"></a>

            <div class="collectionInfo">

                <div class="arrow">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/arrow.png"/></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collectionCopy">
                    <a href="#">
                    <p>Harbourne</p>
                    <p>Colourways (7)</p>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end collectionInfo -->

        </div> <!-- end collectionImg -->

        <div class="collectionImg">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/OT854_espresso_top.jpg"></a>

            <div class="collectionInfo">

                <div class="arrow">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/arrow.png"/></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collectionCopy">
                    <a href="#">
                    <p>Harbourne</p>
                    <p>Colourways (7)</p>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end collectionInfo -->

        </div> <!-- end collectionImg -->

        <div class="collectionImg">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/OT854_sable_top.jpg"></a>

            <div class="collectionInfo">

                <div class="arrow">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/arrow.png"/></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collectionCopy">
                    <a href="#">
                    <p>Harbourne</p>
                    <p>Colourways (7)</p>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end collectionInfo -->

        </div> <!-- end collectionImg -->

        <div class="collectionImg">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/OT850_toffee_top.jpg"></a>

            <div class="collectionInfo">

                <div class="arrow">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://test.gpjbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/arrow.png"/></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collectionCopy">
                    <a href="#">
                    <p>Harbourne</p>
                    <p>Colourways (7)</p>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end collectionInfo -->

        </div> <!-- end collectionImg -->

    </div> <!-- end allImg -->

</div> <!-- end contentBox -->
```

Comment: **I changed the percentages for a 6 column layout on a desktop view (3 on tablet), but this is just not displaying right.** What was it's initial value and what you've changed it to? And do you use any Framework like Bootstrap?

Comment: It seems the `clear` is not defined on the good element in the line. Could you share the css associated to your grid?

Comment: No bootstrap. For the original one (4 column) I used 25% desktop, 50% tablet and it displayed fine on tablet and phone. For this page (6 column) I used 16% desktop, 33% tablet and this is what it did. On the tablet, it looks fine. On my phone, it shows this way. When I use the desktop to shrink the window down, it kind of jumps from proper view to this view. I'm still new to responsive, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add following CSS rule to your CSS file inside this media query

`@media screen and (min-width: 420px) and (max-width: 995px)`

```
.collectionImg:nth-child(4n+0){
    clear:left;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0un8zezr/2/)**

[More about :nth-child pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)

Comment: It worked! Thank you, Ramis. I'll read up on the `:nth-child`, since I only know the basics of it. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Here also some information about **[clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)**